# iterating through object and storing in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
var selectCheckbox = [];
for (i = 0; i <= escConfigForm.chapters.size; i++) {
    if (escConfigForm.chapters['i']) {
        selectCheckbox.push({
            id: $scope.chapters['i'].id,
            name: $scope.chapters['i'].name
        });
    }
    console.log(selectedCheckbox);
```

I'm creating an array to return objects into it which comes from `$scope.chapters`
which looks like:

```
[{"name":"Chapter 9: Negative Messages","id":"832115"},{"name":"Chapter 13: Proposals, Business Plans, and Formal Business Reports","id":"832124"}].
```

Simultaneously I wanted to compare them with `escConfigForm.chapters` which shows me an object `(0:true 1:true 2:true);`

`escConfigForm.chapters.size` / `escConfigForm.chapters.length` seems to be `undefined`.

Comment: Objects don't have a `length` property, you can do `Object.keys(object).length` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those oddly complicated things you run into in JS. For instance, Object.keys() will return the fields in the object you give it *as well as* the fields in its prototype.

Angular has the [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) convenience method which specifically notes it does not iterate over inherited properties. Alas, I doubt an order is guaranteed, but then again maybe it is. . .